# svg mask does not work in chrome but works in FF

Tags: svg, cross-browser, mask

I'm out of ideas here, I made a animated svg to mask an image using javascript, pretty simple but it does not work in chrome and edge, but in firefox it works fine, the console don't trow any errors, I read the documentation and technically it should be working. My main target are mobile devices, so this must be working on chrome :( This is the structure of the html and the script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div id="logo"><img src="imgs/realestate_logo.svg" alt="" /></div>
        <div class="combo">
            <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 400 300">
                <defs>
                    <mask id="mask">
                        <rect fill="#000000" x="0" y="0" width="400" height="300"></rect>
                        <circle fill="#FFFFFF" cx="200" cy="150" r="0" />
                        <circle fill="#FFFFFF" cx="200" cy="150" r="0" />
                        <circle fill="#FFFFFF" cx="200" cy="150" r="0" />
                        <circle fill="#FFFFFF" cx="200" cy="150" r="0" />
                        <circle fill="#FFFFFF" cx="200" cy="150" r="0" />
                        <circle fill="#FFFFFF" cx="200" cy="150" r="0" />
                        <circle fill="#FFFFFF" cx="200" cy="150" r="0" />
                        <circle fill="#FFFFFF" cx="200" cy="150" r="0" />
                        <circle fill="#FFFFFF" cx="200" cy="150" r="0" />
                        <circle fill="#FFFFFF" cx="200" cy="150" r="0" />
                        <circle fill="#FFFFFF" cx="200" cy="150" r="0" />
                        <circle fill="#FFFFFF" cx="200" cy="150" r="0" />
                        <circle fill="#FFFFFF" cx="200" cy="150" r="0" />
                        <circle fill="#FFFFFF" cx="200" cy="150" r="0" />
                        <circle fill="#FFFFFF" cx="200" cy="150" r="0" />
                        <circle fill="#FFFFFF" cx="200" cy="150" r="0" />
                    </mask>
                </defs>
            </svg>
            <div class="container">
                <img src="imgs/villa.webp" alt="Your Image">
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div class="texto">
            <p>Soy el texto</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener('load', function() {

            // Logo Animation
            const logoElement = document.getElementById("logo");
            setTimeout(() => {
                logoElement.style.opacity = "1";
                logoElement.style.transform = "translateY(0)";
            }, 500);  // Delay for half a second before starting the logo animation

            const img = document.querySelector(".container img");
            const circles = document.querySelectorAll("#mask circle");

            // Image dimensions and circle animation
            const width = img.naturalWidth;
            const height = img.naturalHeight;
            const aspectRatio = (height / width) * 100;
            const comboElement = document.querySelector(".combo");
            comboElement.style.paddingBottom = `${aspectRatio}%`;
            animateCurrentCircle(0);

            // Add event listener for window resize
            window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
                animateCurrentCircle(0);  // Reset the circle animation upon resizing
            });

            function getRandom(min, max) {
                return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
            }

            function animateCurrentCircle(index) {
                if (index >= circles.length) {
                    index = 0;
                }

                const svgWidth = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(document.querySelector("svg")).width);
                const svgHeight = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(document.querySelector("svg")).height);

                let maxi = Math.min(svgWidth, svgHeight) / 2;
                const r = getRandom(maxi / 4, maxi);
                const maxCx = svgWidth - r;
                const minCx = r;
                const maxCy = svgHeight - r;
                const minCy = r;
                const cx = getRandom(minCx, maxCx);
                const cy = getRandom(minCy, maxCy);

                const circle = circles[index];
                circle.setAttribute("r", r);
                circle.setAttribute("cx", cx);
                circle.setAttribute("cy", cy);

                setTimeout(() => {
                    animateCurrentCircle(index + 1);
                }, 400);
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

And this is the css:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Addington';
    src: url('../fonts/AddingtonCF-Light.ttf') format('truetype');
}

body, html {
    height: 100%; 
    margin: 0;   
    padding: 0;  
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    font-family: 'Addington', serif; 
}

.main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; 
    align-items: center;   
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    height: 100%;         
    max-width: 1200px;     
    margin: 0 auto;        
    padding: 0px;          
    background-color: #fff; 
    gap: 10px;
}

#logo img {
    width: 90%;            
    min-width: 300px;      
    max-width: 400px;       
    height: auto;          
    display: block;        
    margin: 0 auto;        
}

#logo, .combo {
    width: 100%;          
    position: relative;    
}

.combo {
    width: 90%;            
    max-width: 720px;      
    min-width: 300px;     
    margin: 0 auto;        
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: auto;
}

.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;          
    height: 100%;         
}

.container img {
    width: 100%;          
    display: block;        
    object-fit: cover;
    /*-webkit-mask-image: url(#mask);*/
    -webkit-mask-size: cover;
    -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat; /* Added to ensure mask doesn't repeat */
    /*mask-image: url(#mask);*/
    mask-size: cover;
    mask-repeat: no-repeat; /* Added to ensure mask doesn't repeat */
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-mask: url(#mask);
    mask: url(#mask);
}

svg {
    position: absolute;   
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;          
    height: 100%;         
}

circle {
    transition: all 5s ease;
}

.texto {
    font-size: 18px;
}

#logo {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50px);
    transition: opacity 1s, transform 1s;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks!!!

Comment: If you think you've found a Chrome bug, report it to [Chrome's bugtracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list) - unless you can find it there already.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox is currently the only browser engine supporting referenced svg masks applied to HTML elements. So your also mask won't work on apple mobile devices (safari/webkit). See also ["css-tricks: Clipping and Masking in CSS"](https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/#aa-browser-support)

As a workaround, you can replace your `<img>` elements with inline svg `<image>` elements.

```
<div class="container">
  <svg width="100%" height="100%">
    <description>Your Image</description>
    <image class="masked" href="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

`preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"` scales and fits an image similar to CSS `object-fit:cover`

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  // Logo Animation
  const logoElement = document.getElementById("logo");
  setTimeout(() => {
    logoElement.style.opacity = "1";
    logoElement.style.transform = "translateY(0)";
  }, 500); // Delay for half a second before starting the logo animation

  //const img = document.querySelector(".container img");
  const img = document.querySelector(".container image");
  const circles = document.querySelectorAll("#mask circle");

  const {
    width,
    height
  } = img.getBBox();

  // Image dimensions and circle animation
  const imgParentSvg = img.closest("svg");
  imgParentSvg.setAttribute("viewBox", `0 0 ${width} ${height}`);

  animateCurrentCircle(0);

  // Add event listener for window resize
  window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
    animateCurrentCircle(0); // Reset the circle animation upon resizing
  });

  function getRandom(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  }

  function animateCurrentCircle(index) {
    if (index >= circles.length) {
      index = 0;
    }

    const svgWidth = parseFloat(
      getComputedStyle(document.querySelector("svg")).width
    );
    const svgHeight = parseFloat(
      getComputedStyle(document.querySelector("svg")).height
    );

    let maxi = Math.min(svgWidth, svgHeight) / 2;
    const r = getRandom(maxi / 4, maxi);
    const maxCx = svgWidth - r;
    const minCx = r;
    const maxCy = svgHeight - r;
    const minCy = r;
    const cx = getRandom(minCx, maxCx);
    const cy = getRandom(minCy, maxCy);

    const circle = circles[index];
    circle.setAttribute("r", r);
    circle.setAttribute("cx", cx);
    circle.setAttribute("cy", cy);

    setTimeout(() => {
      animateCurrentCircle(index + 1);
    }, 400);
  }
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  font-family: 'Addington', serif;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #fff;
  gap: 10px;
}

#logo img {
  width: 90%;
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#logo,
.combo {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.combo {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 720px;
  min-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: auto;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container image {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-mask: url(#mask);
  mask: url(#mask);
}

svg {
  border: 1px solid #ccc
}

circle {
  transition: all 5s ease;
}

.texto {
  font-size: 18px;
}

#logo {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50px);
  transition: opacity 1s, transform 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div id="logo"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/230/100/100" alt="" /></div>
  <div class="combo">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 400 300">
      <defs>
        <mask id="mask">
          <rect fill="#000000" x="0" y="0" width="400" height="300"></rect>
          <circle fill="#FFFFFF" cx="200" cy="150" r="0" />
          <circle fill="#FFFFFF" cx="200" cy="150" r="0" />
          <circle fill="#FFFFFF" cx="200" cy="150" r="0" />
          <circle fill="#FFFFFF" cx="200" cy="150" r="0" />
          <circle fill="#FFFFFF" cx="200" cy="150" r="0" />
          <circle fill="#FFFFFF" cx="200" cy="150" r="0" />
          <circle fill="#FFFFFF" cx="200" cy="150" r="0" />
          <circle fill="#FFFFFF" cx="200" cy="150" r="0" />
          <circle fill="#FFFFFF" cx="200" cy="150" r="0" />
          <circle fill="#FFFFFF" cx="200" cy="150" r="0" />
          <circle fill="#FFFFFF" cx="200" cy="150" r="0" />
          <circle fill="#FFFFFF" cx="200" cy="150" r="0" />
          <circle fill="#FFFFFF" cx="200" cy="150" r="0" />
          <circle fill="#FFFFFF" cx="200" cy="150" r="0" />
          <circle fill="#FFFFFF" cx="200" cy="150" r="0" />
          <circle fill="#FFFFFF" cx="200" cy="150" r="0" />
        </mask>
      </defs>
    </svg>
    <div class="container">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%">
        <description>Your Image</description>
        <image class="masked" href="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" />
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr />
  <div class="texto">
    <p>Soy el texto</p>
  </div>
</div>
```